# Behat 3.0 features folder/path

Tags: php, laravel, behat

I am trying to setup Behat 3.0. I want to change the path of where my features go.

Currently, my `behat.yml` config looks like this:

```
default:
    autoload:
        '': app/tests/acceptance
```

Running `behat --init` wil create the `acceptance/FeatureContext.php` in the `app/tests` directory.

However, it will  create the `features` folder in the root of my project. I would instead want this `features` folder to be placed in the `app/tests/acceptance` folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Behat 3 has support for [suites](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html) and [profiles](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/6.profiles.html).

Only thing you have to do is to add **custom paths** to the **default profile**:

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/app/tests/acceptance
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/app/tests/acceptance/features ]
```

### Tip 1

Always use the `%paths.base%` variable to be able to run your Behat tests from a different directory.

### Tip 2

Depending on Behat's PSR-0 autoload mechanism can be problematic when you'll have more contexts implemented.

Good practice is to use the composer's PSR-4 autoload mechanism to be able to run namespaced Behat features.

After you have setup Behat as in the example above you need to delete the autoload section in the bahat.yml and add `contexts` to the `default` profile:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/app/tests/acceptance/features ]
      contexts: [ MyApp\Tests\Acceptance\FeatureContext ]
```

Add autoloading configuration to `composer.json`:

```
{
    [...]
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\Tests\\Acceptance\\": "app/tests/acceptance"
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

And then simply dump the autoloader with `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered a lot with it, so here is my (simple) solution, in the hope it will save time to someone oneday. Using behat 3.8.1.

My files layout:

```
behat.yml
test/acceptance/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php
test/acceptance/features/myAcceptanceTest.feature
```

My behat.yml file:

```yaml
default:
  autoload: [ '%paths.base%/test/acceptance/bootstrap' ]
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ '%paths.base%/test/acceptance/features' ]
      contexts: [ test\acceptance\bootstrap\FeatureContext ]
```

Unlike everything I read, including the documentation, I had to add quotes to be able to use the `%paths.base%` variable.

The `autoload` parameter tells Behat where to find your context php file(s).

The `paths` parameter tells Behat where to find your features file(s).

The tricky part is the `contexts` parameter: it gives the namespace path of your FeatureContext class. You need to make sure that it matches what you have at the top of your `FeatureContext.php` file:

```php
<?php

namespace test\acceptance\bootstrap;
...
class FeatureContext implements Context
{
...
}
```

With all these planets properly aligned, it works beautifully. From the project folder:

```
$ vendor/bin/behat
```

HTH